# unix - automatically determine field separator and record (EOL) separator?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Say you have 20 files and you don't won't to look at each one but instead have a script determine the format of the file.

ie bash findFileFormat direcName

Then loops through each file in a directory and print out the filename plus whether it has a delimiter (in which case is it a comma, pipe or otherwise) or fixed with for field separator and then what is the record separator. ie CR, LF, Ctrl+Z character.etc

I was thinking because some files may have a lot of pipes and commas in the data, that it could use a count of each character per line to determine what the delimiter is --> if this process does not produce consistent numbers of the character per line it is safe to assume that the file uses a fixed width field separator.

Is there a command or script that can be used to determine these 2 bits of info for each file?

Comment: No matter how you code your program, you'd have to design a very complex human-like logic to accurately do what you want. Just think of all the things your brain does when you open an file in order to determine the format. Sometimes it will be easy to spot (i.e. you see tabs and all columns are aligned) but sometimes it won't be that clear. Truth is, no matter how you do it, the best you can do is give a "best possible match" perhaps, given a list of possible delimiters, but to just find precisely what it is for any type of file is far from simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small python script that will do as a starting point for what you need:

```
import sys

separators = [',', '|']
file_name = sys.argv[1]

def sep_cnt(line):
  return {sep:line.count(sep) for sep in separators}

with open(file_name, 'r') as inf:
  lines = inf.readlines()

cnts = [sep_cnt(line) for line in lines]
print(cnts)

def cnts_red(a, b):
  c = {}
  for k, v in a.iteritems():
    if v > 0 and v == b[k]:
      c[k] = v
  return c

final = reduce(cnts_red, cnts[1:], cnts[0])

if len(final) == 0:
  ftype = 'fixed'
else:
  ftype = 'sep by ' + str(final.iteritems().next()[0])

print(ftype)
```

Name the above heur_sep.py and run this somewhere safe (e.g. /tmp):

```
# Prepare
rm *.txt

# Commas
cat >f1.txt <<e
a,a,a,a
b,b,b,b
c,c,c,c
e

# Pipes
cat >f2.txt <<e
a|a|a|a
b|b|b|b
c|c|c|c
e

# Fixed width
cat >f3.txt <<e
1  2  3
1  2  3
1  2  3
e

# Fixed width with commas
cat >f4.txt <<e
1, 2  3
1  2, 3
1  2, 3,
e

for i in *.txt; do
  echo --- $i
  python heur_sep.py $i
done
```

You would have to do some more work to make this resistant to different kinds of errors, but should be a good starting point. Hope this helps.